# How can I update BIOS for my HP desktop with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bios, desktop

I have HP Desktop (Elite 8200 Small Form Factor) with Windows 10 upgraded.

I search HP website and searched my desktop model number but they don't seem to support Windows 10. How can I update the BIOS?

Comment: The same way you update it today?  The application is a Windows based application it will work on any (Microsoft) supported version of Windows.

Comment: BIOS is not OS version specific you can install the windows version.

Comment: @vembutech Really? I downloaded the appropriate version of BIOS update software from HP website, but it says "This is not compatible with this version of Windows. Check your software provider if there is a version compatible with 64-bit Windows."